# Quelles seraient d’autres façons d’écrire « Je suis sous Prozac » ou « Je suis sous antidépresseur »

Tags: choix-de-mot, formulation-idiomatique, anglicismes, reformulation

J’ai l’impression que « être sous » s’apparente à un tour syntaxique propre à l’anglais (to be under).

> Je suis un traitement par le Prozac?

> Je suis en traitement par le Prozac?

Comment: En anglais, on ne dit pas to be under pour un médicament. On dit: to be on a medication.

Comment: @Lambie Merci pour votre commentaire, Lambie. Et que pensez-vous des deux variantes que j’ai proposées?

Comment: Et bien, on entend aussi: être sous [nom du médicament]. Le Prozac est un antidépressur, alors, pourquoi pas? :)

Comment: @Lambie Je parlais des deux variantes citées dans les détails de la question. 

Comment: C’est moi qui n’ai pas été assez clair.

Comment: Ah, d'accord. [Actuellement] Je suis un traitement antidépressif. Par contre, personellemet, je ne dirais pas: par le Prozac. Il faut dire autre chose, à mon avis. comme: en prenant du Prozac.

Comment: @Lambie … une formule usuelle avec *sous* : « Je suis en pleine dépression, *sous* Prozac ». Le contexte induit en sous-entendu, que les effets secondaires néfastes de ces médicaments ne sont pas négligeables.

Comment: @Personne Je vous remercie, Personne, pour ce complément d’information.

Comment: @TeleportingGoat I said that in my first comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

« Être sous *médicament* » est parfois considéré comme un anglicisme, en particulier si on considère qu'il s'agit d'un raccourci de la forme « être sous traitement au *médicament* » (*under treatment* / *to undergo treatment*).

Par exemple la [BDL](http://bdl.oqlf.gouv.qc.ca/bdl/gabarit_bdl.asp?t1=1&id=2462) indique:

> La préposition anglaise *under* ne suit pas tout à fait les mêmes règles d’emploi que la préposition française sous. Aussi faut-il prendre garde à ne pas employer systématiquement sous là où l’anglais utilise *under* : ainsi, les expressions *under certain circumstances, under examination, under discussion, under study, under treatment, under observation,* etc., appellent en français l’utilisation d’une autre préposition, par exemple *en*, *à* ou *dans*.

Je serais plus mesuré car *être sous traitement* est utilisé en français depuis au moins le milieu du XIX<sup>e</sup> siècle :

> *Il restait 375 malades sous traitement au 1er octobre.*
> Bulletin médical belge, 1837

Il a peut-être débuté comme belgicisme, influencé par le néerlandais *onder behandeling* mais s'est généralisé ensuite dans toute la francophonie.

« Être sous *médicament* » est attesté dans le TLFi :

[Sous](https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/sous/1):

> − *MÉD. (Être) sous antibiotiques, sous perfusion.* Soumis à l'action de. *Pour avoir fait une telle œuvre, j'accepterais volontiers d'être amputé d'une jambe. Oui, je donnerais bien une jambe. Mais, attention, attention! amputé sous anesthésie* (Duhamel, *Nuit St-Jean*, 1935, p. 168).

On le trouve aussi un sens proche dans la 8<sup>e</sup> édition du dictionnaire de l'Académie (1935)

> *[SOUS](https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/academie8/sous/1) indique encore la Cause. Sous le coup de la surprise. Agir sous l'empire de la colère. Sous l'influence d'un médicament.*

Tu peux donc conserver les phrases *Je suis sous Prozac* ou *sous antidépresseur*. Tes propositions de remplacement sont peu naturelles. Tu pourrais les modifier comme suit :

> Je suis sous traitement au Prozac.
> Je suis un traitement au Prozac.
> Je suis sous traitement par antidépresseur.

Comment: "Être sous médicament » est parfois considéré comme un anglicisme, en particulier si on considère qu'il s'agit d'un raccourci de la forme « être sous traitement au médicament » (under treatment)". C'est faux. On ne dit pas "under treatment" comme ça en anglais. On dit: being treated with [medication]. J'avais déjà signalé ce fait.

Answer (score 0):

Je suis traité par Prozac. Je suis traité par un antidépresseur.